# partition of anova and comparisons (orthogonal single df) in r

Tags: r, anova, contrast, orthogonal

I want to do single df orthogonal contrast in anova (fixed or mixed model). Here is just example:

```
require(nlme)
data (Alfalfa)
  Variety: a factor with levels Cossack, Ladak, and Ranger
  Date : a factor with levels None S1 S20 O7
  Block: a factor with levels 1 2 3 4 5 6
  Yield : a numeric vector
```

These data are described in Snedecor and Cochran (1980) as an example
of a split-plot design. The treatment structure used in the experiment
 was a 3\times4 full factorial, with three varieties of alfalfa and four
 dates of third cutting in 1943. The experimental units were arranged
 into six blocks, each subdivided into four plots. The varieties of alfalfa
 (Cossac, Ladak, and Ranger) were assigned randomly to the blocks and
 the dates of third cutting (None, S1—September 1, S20—September 20,
 and O7—October 7) were randomly assigned to the plots.
All four dates were used on each block.

```
model<-with (Alfalfa, aov(Yield~Variety*Date +Error(Block/Date/Variety)))

    > summary(model)

Error: Block
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  5   4.15    0.83

Error: Block:Date
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
Date       3 1.9625  0.6542   17.84 3.29e-05 ***
Residuals 15 0.5501  0.0367
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Block:Date:Variety
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Variety       2 0.1780 0.08901   1.719  0.192
Variety:Date  6 0.2106 0.03509   0.678  0.668
Residuals    40 2.0708 0.05177
```

I want to perform some comparison (orthogonal contrasts within a group), for example for date, two contrasts:

```
   (a) S1 vs others (S20 O7)
   (b) S20 vs 07,
```

For variety factor two contrasts:

```
  (c)  Cossack vs others (Ladak and Ranger)
   (d) Ladak vs Ranger
```

Thus the anova output would look like:

```
Error: Block
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  5   4.15    0.83

Error: Block:Date
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
Date       3 1.9625  0.6542   17.84 3.29e-05 ***
       (a) S1 vs others    ?        ?
       (b)  S20 vs 07       ?        ?
Residuals 15 0.5501  0.0367
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Block:Date:Variety
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Variety       2 0.1780 0.08901   1.719  0.192
     (c)  Cossack vs others ?        ?    ?
     (d)  Ladak vs Ranger    ?       ?     ?
Variety:Date  6 0.2106 0.03509   0.678  0.668
Residuals    40 2.0708 0.05177
```

How can I perform this ? ....................

Comment: See any textbook on ANOVA on how exactly you have to define the contrasts, and `?contrasts` on how you have to apply them in R.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the `Date` level `None`?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein no, I need is, 'None' is not 'NA'

Comment: @JorisMeys , contrasts are very poorly documented in R, including `?contrasts`. Nobody should be RTFM-ed to that particular FM.

Comment: I think the question might be simpler than you assume -- if you use contrasts in the model then Anova() gives only a summary line and does not partition the sum of squares as shown in the example table. In the summary the coefficients are separated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why use ANOVA? You can use `lme` from the `nlme` package and in addition to the hypothesis tests `aov` gives you, you also get interpretable estimates of the effect sizes and the directions of the effects. At any rate, two approaches come to mind:

- Specify contrasts on the variables manually, as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52252/how-to-specify-a-contrast-matrix-in-r-for-the-difference-between-one-level-and).
- Install the `multcomp` package and use `glht`.

`glht` is a little opinionated about models that are multivariate in their predictors. Long story short, though, if you were to create a diagonal matrix `cm0` with the same dimensions and dimnames as the `vcov` of your model (let's assume it's an `lme` fit called `model0`), then `summary(glht(model0,linfct=cm0))` should give the same estimates, SEs, and test statistics as `summary(model0)$tTable` (but *incorrect* p-values). Now, if you mess around with linear combinations of rows from `cm0` and create new matrices with the same number of columns as `cm0` but these linear combinations as rows, you'll eventually figure out the pattern to creating a matrix that will give you the intercept estimate for each cell (check it against `predict(model0,level=0)`). Now, another matrix with differences between various rows of this matrix will give you corresponding between-group differences. The same approach but with numeric values set to 1 instead of 0 can be used to get the slope estimates for each cell. Then the differences between these slope estimates can be used to get between-group slope differences.

Three things to keep in mind:

- As I said the p-values are going to be wrong for models other than `lm`, (possibly, haven't tried) `aov`, and certain survival models. This is because `glht` assumes a `z` distribution instead of a `t` distribution by default (except for `lm`). To get correct p-values, take the test statistic `glht` calculates and manually do `2*pt(abs(`**STAT**`),df=`**DF**`,lower=F)` to get the two-tailed p-value where **STAT** is the test statistic returned by `glht` and **DF** is the `df` from the corresponding type of default contrast in `summary(model0)$tTable`.
- Your contrasts probably no longer test independent hypotheses, and multiple testing correction is necessary, if it wasn't already. Run the p-values through `p.adjust`.
- This is my own distillation of a lot of handwaving from professors and colleagues, and a lot of reading of Crossvalidated and Stackoverflow on related topics. I could be wrong in multiple ways, and if I am, hopefully someone more knowlegeable will correct us both.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry about not giving more detailed, step-by-step code. One of my ongoing projects is to create a self-documenting Shiny app that does all this for the masses, so if I'm going to spend a lot of time writing/thinking about contrasts and mixed effects, I should be doing it on that because it will ultimately help more people.